# Aggregating Facts in the CLIPS Expert System to Find a Maximum

Tags: expert-system, clips

I'm trying to clarify my understanding of semantics in the Clips expert system, so I'm trying to write some simple rules to aggregate a list of facts to find the fact with the highest slot value. The metaphor I'm using is that of a simple agent trying to decide whether it should eat or sleep. Facts describing the agent's states are expanded into potential actions, and then a rule tries to find the final action with the highest utility.

This is my code:

```
(clear)

(deftemplate state 
    (slot name) 
    (slot level (type NUMBER)) 
) 
(deftemplate action 
    (slot name) 
    (slot utility (type NUMBER)) 
    (slot final (type INTEGER) (default 0)) 
) 
(defrule eat-when-hungry "" 
    (state (name hungry) (level ?level)) 
    => 
    (assert (action (name eat) (utility ?level))) 
) 
(defrule sleep-when-sleepy "" 
    (state (name sleepy) (level ?level)) 
    => 
    (assert (action (name sleep) (utility ?level))) 
) 
(defrule find-final-action "" 
    ?current_final <- (action (name ?current_final_action) (utility ? 
current_final_utility) (final 1)) 
    (action (name ?other_action) (utility ?other_utility) (final 0)) 
    (neq ?current_final_action ?other_action) 
    (< ?current_final_action ?other_action) 
    => 
    (modify ?current_final (name ?other_action) (utility ? 
other_utility)) 
) 
(assert (action (name none) (utility 0.0) (final 1))) 
(assert (state (name hungry) (level 0.5))) 
(assert (state (name sleepy) (level 0.1))) 
(run) 
(facts)
```

After running this, I would expect the final action to be:

```
(action (name eat) (utility 0.5) (final 1))
```

However, Clips evaluates it to:

```
(action (name none) (utility 0.0) (final 1))
```

indicating the find-final-action rule never activates. Why is this? How would you iterate over a group of facts and find the one with the min/max slot value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule had a couple of errors in it. Here is the corrected version:

```
(defrule find-final-action "" 
    ?current_final <- (action (name ?current_final_action) 
                              (utility ?current_final_utility) (final 1)) 
    (action (name ?other_action) (utility ?other_utility) (final 0)) 
    (test (neq ?current_final_action ?other_action))
    (test (< ?current_final_utility ?other_utility)) 
    => 
    (modify ?current_final (name ?other_action) (utility ?other_utility)))
```

An alternate method which does not require storing intermediate computations and multiple rule firings is this:

```
(defrule find-final-action-2 "" 
    (declare (salience -10)) ; lower salience to allow all actions to be asserted first
    (action (name ?action) (utility ?utility)) 
    (not (action (utility ?other_utility&:(> ?other_utility ?utility))))
    => 
    (printout t "Final action is " ?action crlf))
```